# Colorbox y select

Tags: php, javascript, select

Tengo el siguiente código, cuyo objetivo es que al seleccionar una opción del select, abra un colorbox con información. El select está en una tabla dinámica y se replica. El problema es que solo la url de cada opción funciona en la primera fila, en las siguientes aparece:"The requested URL /undefined was not found on this server". Alguien que pueda mostrarme en dónde está el error en JavaScript.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$('select[name="acciones"]').change(function(){
    
    var link = $('select[name="acciones"]').find(':selected').attr('href');
    
    $.colorbox({iframe:true, fastIframe:false, width:"450px", height:"480px", transition:"fade", scrolling   : false, href:link});
});
</script>
```

```html
<select name="acciones">
          <option></option>
          <option href="colorbox.php">Opcion 1</option>
          <option href="fechas.php">Opcion 2</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: Creo si usas `this` en lugar de un selector funcionaría: `var link = $(this).find(':selected').attr('href');`

Comment: @blonfu efectivamente, sí era eso, muchas gracias, logré lo que quería